# AES (aes-cbc-128, aes-cbc-192, aes-cbc-256) encryption/decryption WITHOUT openssl C

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, aes

I want to have a program written in C that can encode / decode a string with AES-CBC without the help of a big library like openssl.

GOAL:

Encode / decode string with passphrase:

The app needs to hence accept 3 input parameters...

1. input string (to be encoded) / or already encoded string (to be decoded)
2. passphrase which is used to encode / decode the string with
3. encode or decode indicator

I am new to C (I can code in C#).

I have found https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES128-C which I would need to configure but I am unsure if the functions are enough to do what I want (see above)

My current "main" code is here, it accepts the 3 input parameters and then calls the function encode / decode based on the 3rd parameter ("e" or "d").

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
      printf("i = %d, argv = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    if (argc < 4)
    printf("missing args: input_text passphrase function\n");
    else {

        /*
        ... argv[1]; input_string
        ... argv[2]; passphrase
        ... argv[3]; function
        */

        //encode if e
        if( argv[3] == "e" ){
            printf("encoded: " + encode(argv[1], argv[2]) );
        } else { //decode else
            printf("decoded: " + decode(argv[1], argv[2]) );
        }
        //printf("input: " + input);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Enable both ECB and CBC mode. Note this can be done before including aes.h or at compile-time.
// E.g. with GCC by using the -D flag: gcc -c aes.c -DCBC=0 -DECB=1
#define CBC 1
#define ECB 1

#include "aes.h"

static void phex(uint8_t* str);
static void test_encrypt_ecb(void);
static void test_decrypt_ecb(void);
static void test_encrypt_ecb_verbose(void);
static void test_encrypt_cbc(void);
static void test_decrypt_cbc(void);



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
      printf("i = %d, argv = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    if (argc < 4)
    printf("missing args: input_text passphrase function\n");
    else {

        /*
        ... argv[1]; input_string
        ... argv[2]; passphrase
        ... argv[3]; function
        */

        //encode if e
        if( argv[3] == "e" ){
            printf("encoded: " + encode(argv[1], argv[2]) );
        } else { //decode else
            printf("decoded: " + decode(argv[1], argv[2]) );
        }
        //printf("input: " + input);
    }

    return 0;
}



// prints string as hex
static void phex(uint8_t* str)
{
    unsigned char i;
    for(i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
        printf("%.2x", str[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

static void test_encrypt_ecb_verbose(void)
{
    // Example of more verbose verification

    uint8_t i, buf[64], buf2[64];

    // 128bit key
    uint8_t key[16] =        { (uint8_t) 0x2b, (uint8_t) 0x7e, (uint8_t) 0x15, (uint8_t) 0x16, (uint8_t) 0x28, (uint8_t) 0xae, (uint8_t) 0xd2, (uint8_t) 0xa6, (uint8_t) 0xab, (uint8_t) 0xf7, (uint8_t) 0x15, (uint8_t) 0x88, (uint8_t) 0x09, (uint8_t) 0xcf, (uint8_t) 0x4f, (uint8_t) 0x3c };
    // 512bit text
    uint8_t plain_text[64] = { (uint8_t) 0x6b, (uint8_t) 0xc1, (uint8_t) 0xbe, (uint8_t) 0xe2, (uint8_t) 0x2e, (uint8_t) 0x40, (uint8_t) 0x9f, (uint8_t) 0x96, (uint8_t) 0xe9, (uint8_t) 0x3d, (uint8_t) 0x7e, (uint8_t) 0x11, (uint8_t) 0x73, (uint8_t) 0x93, (uint8_t) 0x17, (uint8_t) 0x2a,
                               (uint8_t) 0xae, (uint8_t) 0x2d, (uint8_t) 0x8a, (uint8_t) 0x57, (uint8_t) 0x1e, (uint8_t) 0x03, (uint8_t) 0xac, (uint8_t) 0x9c, (uint8_t) 0x9e, (uint8_t) 0xb7, (uint8_t) 0x6f, (uint8_t) 0xac, (uint8_t) 0x45, (uint8_t) 0xaf, (uint8_t) 0x8e, (uint8_t) 0x51,
                               (uint8_t) 0x30, (uint8_t) 0xc8, (uint8_t) 0x1c, (uint8_t) 0x46, (uint8_t) 0xa3, (uint8_t) 0x5c, (uint8_t) 0xe4, (uint8_t) 0x11, (uint8_t) 0xe5, (uint8_t) 0xfb, (uint8_t) 0xc1, (uint8_t) 0x19, (uint8_t) 0x1a, (uint8_t) 0x0a, (uint8_t) 0x52, (uint8_t) 0xef,
                               (uint8_t) 0xf6, (uint8_t) 0x9f, (uint8_t) 0x24, (uint8_t) 0x45, (uint8_t) 0xdf, (uint8_t) 0x4f, (uint8_t) 0x9b, (uint8_t) 0x17, (uint8_t) 0xad, (uint8_t) 0x2b, (uint8_t) 0x41, (uint8_t) 0x7b, (uint8_t) 0xe6, (uint8_t) 0x6c, (uint8_t) 0x37, (uint8_t) 0x10 };

    memset(buf, 0, 64);
    memset(buf2, 0, 64);

    // print text to encrypt, key and IV
    printf("ECB encrypt verbose:\n\n");
    printf("plain text:\n");
    for(i = (uint8_t) 0; i < (uint8_t) 4; ++i)
    {
        phex(plain_text + i * (uint8_t) 16);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("key:\n");
    phex(key);
    printf("\n");

    // print the resulting cipher as 4 x 16 byte strings
    printf("ciphertext:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        AES128_ECB_encrypt(plain_text + (i*16), key, buf+(i*16));
        phex(buf + (i*16));
    }
    printf("\n");
}


static void test_encrypt_ecb(void)
{
  uint8_t key[] = {0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c};
  uint8_t in[]  = {0x6b, 0xc1, 0xbe, 0xe2, 0x2e, 0x40, 0x9f, 0x96, 0xe9, 0x3d, 0x7e, 0x11, 0x73, 0x93, 0x17, 0x2a};
  uint8_t out[] = {0x3a, 0xd7, 0x7b, 0xb4, 0x0d, 0x7a, 0x36, 0x60, 0xa8, 0x9e, 0xca, 0xf3, 0x24, 0x66, 0xef, 0x97};
  uint8_t buffer[16];

  AES128_ECB_encrypt(in, key, buffer);

  printf("ECB decrypt: ");

  if(0 == memcmp((char*) out, (char*) buffer, 16))
  {
    printf("SUCCESS!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("FAILURE!\n");
  }
}

static void test_decrypt_cbc(void)
{
  // Example "simulating" a smaller buffer...

  uint8_t key[] = { 0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c };
  uint8_t iv[]  = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };
  uint8_t in[]  = { 0x76, 0x49, 0xab, 0xac, 0x81, 0x19, 0xb2, 0x46, 0xce, 0xe9, 0x8e, 0x9b, 0x12, 0xe9, 0x19, 0x7d,
                    0x50, 0x86, 0xcb, 0x9b, 0x50, 0x72, 0x19, 0xee, 0x95, 0xdb, 0x11, 0x3a, 0x91, 0x76, 0x78, 0xb2,
                    0x73, 0xbe, 0xd6, 0xb8, 0xe3, 0xc1, 0x74, 0x3b, 0x71, 0x16, 0xe6, 0x9e, 0x22, 0x22, 0x95, 0x16, 
                    0x3f, 0xf1, 0xca, 0xa1, 0x68, 0x1f, 0xac, 0x09, 0x12, 0x0e, 0xca, 0x30, 0x75, 0x86, 0xe1, 0xa7 };
  uint8_t out[] = { 0x6b, 0xc1, 0xbe, 0xe2, 0x2e, 0x40, 0x9f, 0x96, 0xe9, 0x3d, 0x7e, 0x11, 0x73, 0x93, 0x17, 0x2a,
                    0xae, 0x2d, 0x8a, 0x57, 0x1e, 0x03, 0xac, 0x9c, 0x9e, 0xb7, 0x6f, 0xac, 0x45, 0xaf, 0x8e, 0x51,
                    0x30, 0xc8, 0x1c, 0x46, 0xa3, 0x5c, 0xe4, 0x11, 0xe5, 0xfb, 0xc1, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x0a, 0x52, 0xef,
                    0xf6, 0x9f, 0x24, 0x45, 0xdf, 0x4f, 0x9b, 0x17, 0xad, 0x2b, 0x41, 0x7b, 0xe6, 0x6c, 0x37, 0x10 };
  uint8_t buffer[64];

  AES128_CBC_decrypt_buffer(buffer+0, in+0,  16, key, iv);
  AES128_CBC_decrypt_buffer(buffer+16, in+16, 16, 0, 0);
  AES128_CBC_decrypt_buffer(buffer+32, in+32, 16, 0, 0);
  AES128_CBC_decrypt_buffer(buffer+48, in+48, 16, 0, 0);

  printf("CBC decrypt: ");

  if(0 == memcmp((char*) out, (char*) buffer, 64))
  {
    printf("SUCCESS!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("FAILURE!\n");
  }
}

static void test_encrypt_cbc(void)
{
  uint8_t key[] = { 0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c };
  uint8_t iv[]  = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };
  uint8_t in[]  = { 0x6b, 0xc1, 0xbe, 0xe2, 0x2e, 0x40, 0x9f, 0x96, 0xe9, 0x3d, 0x7e, 0x11, 0x73, 0x93, 0x17, 0x2a,
                    0xae, 0x2d, 0x8a, 0x57, 0x1e, 0x03, 0xac, 0x9c, 0x9e, 0xb7, 0x6f, 0xac, 0x45, 0xaf, 0x8e, 0x51,
                    0x30, 0xc8, 0x1c, 0x46, 0xa3, 0x5c, 0xe4, 0x11, 0xe5, 0xfb, 0xc1, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x0a, 0x52, 0xef,
                    0xf6, 0x9f, 0x24, 0x45, 0xdf, 0x4f, 0x9b, 0x17, 0xad, 0x2b, 0x41, 0x7b, 0xe6, 0x6c, 0x37, 0x10 };
  uint8_t out[] = { 0x76, 0x49, 0xab, 0xac, 0x81, 0x19, 0xb2, 0x46, 0xce, 0xe9, 0x8e, 0x9b, 0x12, 0xe9, 0x19, 0x7d,
                    0x50, 0x86, 0xcb, 0x9b, 0x50, 0x72, 0x19, 0xee, 0x95, 0xdb, 0x11, 0x3a, 0x91, 0x76, 0x78, 0xb2,
                    0x73, 0xbe, 0xd6, 0xb8, 0xe3, 0xc1, 0x74, 0x3b, 0x71, 0x16, 0xe6, 0x9e, 0x22, 0x22, 0x95, 0x16, 
                    0x3f, 0xf1, 0xca, 0xa1, 0x68, 0x1f, 0xac, 0x09, 0x12, 0x0e, 0xca, 0x30, 0x75, 0x86, 0xe1, 0xa7 };
  uint8_t buffer[64];

  AES128_CBC_encrypt_buffer(buffer, in, 64, key, iv);

  printf("CBC encrypt: ");

  if(0 == memcmp((char*) out, (char*) buffer, 64))
  {
    printf("SUCCESS!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("FAILURE!\n");
  }
}


static void test_decrypt_ecb(void)
{
  uint8_t key[] = {0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c};
  uint8_t in[]  = {0x3a, 0xd7, 0x7b, 0xb4, 0x0d, 0x7a, 0x36, 0x60, 0xa8, 0x9e, 0xca, 0xf3, 0x24, 0x66, 0xef, 0x97};
  uint8_t out[] = {0x6b, 0xc1, 0xbe, 0xe2, 0x2e, 0x40, 0x9f, 0x96, 0xe9, 0x3d, 0x7e, 0x11, 0x73, 0x93, 0x17, 0x2a};
  uint8_t buffer[16];

  AES128_ECB_decrypt(in, key, buffer);

  printf("ECB decrypt: ");

  if(0 == memcmp((char*) out, (char*) buffer, 16))
  {
    printf("SUCCESS!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("FAILURE!\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: `argv[3] == "e"` bad condition expression. Use `strcmp()` or compare each characters like `argv[3][0] == 'e' && argv[3][1] == '\0'`.

Comment: Also why are you using an old-style function definition only for `main()`?

Comment: These expressions `"encoded: " + encode(argv[1], argv[2])` and `"decoded: " + decode(argv[1], argv[2])` looks weird. Also you shouldn't use functions you (or headers you included) decleared or defined before the line in which the functions are used.

Comment: ..because I got this "test.c" file from the github link and I am now trying to edit it and since this is my first confrontation with C this is the only "style" I currently have... feel free to upgrade the code, greatly appreciated

Comment: I advice you should learn basics of C before trying to do complicated things such as encryption.

Comment: I had assumed that there is a sufficient demand for the subject and I hence do not need to brush up that much since I already know C#

Comment: So, encrypt my sensitive files with C code that you "do not need to brush up that much since I already know C#"?  Umm, no thanks.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your constructive comment. This is simply a sample script to encrypt Strings.

Comment: The C implementation of RNCryptor relies on OpenSSL. For this purpose I would perhaps look at MGCryptor, which is a simplified fork (designed for embedded devices). The code is much smaller and self contained, and while tuned to be somewhat weaker than RNCryptor, has the same basic structure. https://github.com/megabri/MGCryptor

Comment: MGCryptor also includes the various primitives you would need and demonstrates one effective way to put them together, so even if you don't use it directly, it is a reasonable introduction to crypto programming. That said, as others have noted, writing a secure format is very difficult and it is very easy to make small errors that undermine its security.

Comment: Ill take a look at MGCryptor then, thank you

Comment: It is not possible to have both ECB and CBC modes. For security use CBC ode with a random iv. Given your level of understanding "C" and encryption you will be much better off using an existing encryption implementation. It is not easy to get encryption correct so that it is secure. Then there is keeping the encryption key secret.

Comment: @DavidDunham Hello, a bit late maybe - if you're still active on this question, I have written a answer below, if it's something wrong with it, please reply!   Thanks,  Regards.

Answer (score 3):

As you state in your Question:

GOAL:

- Encode / decode string with passphrase:
- The app needs to hence accept **3 input parameters**...
- input string (to be encoded)              (**plaintext**)
- or already encoded string (to be decoded) (**ciphertext**)
- passphrase which is used to encode / decode the string with encode or decode indicator

---

---

Here, this is the AES source code, files were too long for me to have in here, but there are 4 files totally:

- taken from:here

http://www.efgh.com/software/rijndael.htm

http://www.efgh.com/software/rijndael.txt

These are:

---

- **encrypt.c**
- **decrypt.c**
- **rijndael.h**
- **rijndael.c**

---

### Download them from

http://www.efgh.com/software/rijndael.txt

---

### **In the file rijndael.txt:**

there will be these 4 lines separating the files:

(here, make 4 individual files with the contents of the = separation =)

So, to show 1 short example, the **RIJNDAEL.H** file,
with following contents:

```
 //=============================== RIJNDAEL.H   ===============================

#ifndef H__RIJNDAEL
#define H__RIJNDAEL

int rijndaelSetupEncrypt(unsigned long *rk, const unsigned char *key,
  int keybits);
int rijndaelSetupDecrypt(unsigned long *rk, const unsigned char *key,
  int keybits);
void rijndaelEncrypt(const unsigned long *rk, int nrounds,
  const unsigned char plaintext[16], unsigned char ciphertext[16]);
void rijndaelDecrypt(const unsigned long *rk, int nrounds,
  const unsigned char ciphertext[16], unsigned char plaintext[16]);

#define KEYLENGTH(keybits) ((keybits)/8)
#define RKLENGTH(keybits)  ((keybits)/8+28)
#define NROUNDS(keybits)   ((keybits)/32+6)

#endif
```

**=============================== DECRYPT.C    ===============================**

**=============================== ENCRYPT.C    ===============================**

**=============================== RIJNDAEL.C   ===============================**

**=============================== RIJNDAEL.H   ===============================**

Do this for each of the files encrypt.c, decrypt.c rijndael.c and finally rijndael.h.

**Test Results:**

### Testing: Compile them and Test them out

---

```
$ gcc -o AES_ENCRYPT RIJNDAEL.C ENCRYPT.C

$ gcc -o AES_DECRYPT RIJNDAEL.C DECRYPT.C
```

---

To encrypt the message
"Your secret message to be encrypted goes here. (The plaintext)"

To the output file "EncodedOutputFile"

```
$ ./AES_ENCRYPT MySecurePassword123 EncodedOutputFile

    Your secret message to be encrypted goes here. (The plaintext)
    CTRL + D to stop.
```

To decrypt the ciphertext (The encrypted file, "EncodedOutputFile"):

```
$ ./AES_DECRYPT MySecurePassword123 EncodedOutputFile
```

> This is the output

> ```
>     Your secret message to be encrypted goes here. (The plaintext)
>     CTRL + D to stop.
> ```

Comment: Edit: I saw now that you're using another code,  Hope my answer can be useful for anyone anyways,  in the future.  I'm quite new here,  thanks.  Regards.

Comment: Please how do you test the decryption code? I used the ./AES_DECRYPT MySecurePassword123 EncodedOutputFile which to my understanding MySecurePassword123 should be some ciphertext and nothing is output to the EncodedOutputFile . Your full guide will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi Hello!  I'M so glad someone found this post helpful! I will of course make a video demonstrating this, and put it on GitHub. Would that help? (I will obviously also write it here, but My writing is a bit fuzzy) I will follow and monitor this closely. `thanks!`

Comment: It will help a lot, hopefully it will decrypt the ciphertext of 5 letter-word of only alphabets alone. I will be really glad and appreciate.

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi Will Of course help!  **I'm just glad to be of *any help! Thanks for reaching out. Working on it immediately.**

Comment: Wowwwwww!!!! @WilliamMartens you are amazing man, thanks a lot, I MUST buy you 5 bottles of beers when you are done. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi Haha, No need.  I uh - need to politely decline your offer. I do not drink; (**But your offer made my day, thank you!**) :)   Coming back when I'm done.

Comment: Just to clarify; I am really not amazing;  But thanks;  Have a great, Great corona-free year on you (and you reading this message, too!) - W.M

Comment: Anyway thanks and I wish you the same, and when you have updated the writeup I will love to know.

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi last comment: If it helped;  Can you up vote it (**Only if it was helpful** if it was not,  don't up vote.)  Have a great day!  thanks.

Comment: The steps above works, but please I will love to know, is there no way to pass the key and the salt instead of the password to decrypt a file? If there is a solution please kindly guide me.

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi Once I have a bit more time - Will look into this.. Stay put;thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi You still there? I have some guides soon I guess would be "helpful" (hopefully) - let me know if it's something of interest. If it is, ill upload them on GitHub.

Comment: Hello @WilliamMartens thanks for the guide, please I am still ready to learn more, I will be very happy to get the guide. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thank can't wait to see it

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi Hello; I am ready to make the guide by now,  so I will upload it on my GitHub page soon.    Just because of the amazing replies I decided to make some improvements on it too, stay put. //Will

Comment: Alright thanks a lot i'm warming up, lol.

Comment: Hello, for over 10 days now I thought I will see the guide that you promised, I cannot get any reply from you again, I hope you are doing good?

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi sorry, preparing for a OSCP but I will try to fit it in time. Wishes.

Comment: I will be glad, and all the best for your upcoming certification(OSCP).

Comment: thanks @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi, still not done though. :P cheers.